# Foursquare API with Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, foursquare, endpoints

I've set up authentication with the Foursquare API and my Rails app, and now it's time to add functionality. I am not too proficient with Rails - it is not my first language. I want to allow a merchant to connect with Foursquare (Working) and then direct the merchant to a page where they can see unique visitors to their venue, the number of checkins to the venue, and who the mayor of the venue is. I know what endpoints to use, I'm just not sure how to implement them in rails. (Access Token, etc.)

Thanks!

**After Answer**

I'm trying to implement Turd Ferguson's answer, but I'm not getting anywhere. I keep getting an error saying the method is undefined. I want to try a simple venue search as soon as the user is authenticated. (Create Action)

Also, I'm using OmniAuth for authentication.

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  require 'foursquare'


  def create
    auth_hash = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    venues = Foursquare::search_venues("starbucks")
    render :text => venues
  end

  def failure
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    render :text => "Logged out!"
  end

  def callback
      code = params[:code]
      @access_token = foursquare.access_token(code, callback_session_url)
      session[:access_token] = @access_token

      redirect_to examples_path
  end


end
```

**foursquare.rb**
    class Foursquare

```
  def self.search_venues(text)
    client.search_venues(:ll => '36.142064,-86.816086', :query => text)
  end

  def self.client
    @client ||= Foursquare2::Client.new(:client_id => '0YO3F0JNZIPVKG1DE01MNPB132D4JZ0QYRQSOWTZQKHHOPKB', :client_secret => 'GMBOGWUNL2GIKZZXQPSLE4BMFNGB5LDHQREH2UKUCK1TJ1L0')
  end


end
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into using a gem such as [foursquare2](https://github.com/mattmueller/foursquare2)?

Using the gem you could create a Foursquare class like:

```
class Foursquare

    def self.search_venues(text)
        client.search_venues(:ll => '36.142064,-86.816086', :query => text)
    end

    def self.client
        @client ||= Foursquare2::Client.new(:client_id => 'your_client_id', :client_secret => 'your_secret')
    end
end
```

You could then call this anywhere you wanted by doing something like:

```
venues = Foursquare::search_venues "foobar"
```

Comment: I saw this gem before, but I just read into the documentation and it will support what I need to do. Where exactly do I call the functions? For example, in which file should I instantiate the client?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an example of how to create a class that you could statically call. I would recommend putting this class in your lib directory. You may have to restart your rails app after adding it for rails to pick up on the new file

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I'll accept your answer once I can successfully implement it.

Comment: I restarted the app, but I get an error saying `undefined method `search_venues' for Foursquare:Module`... any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't it be Foursquare2::Venues::search_venues ? Or am I reading the API wrong?

Comment: I don't think so, the Foursquare2 gem details it a bit differently here: https://github.com/mattmueller/foursquare2 though I may be wrong.

Comment: @mbhnyc Foursquare2 is the name of the gem but I told the OP to create a class called Foursquare that is basically a wrapper around the whole thing just to make it a little more readable/reusable.

Comment: @slicekick It's odd that it's saying `Foursquare:Module`. It sounds like somewhere in your application is a Module called Foursquare that might be causing an issue w/ the addition of this Foursquare class. What happens if you run the rails console and type `Foursquare.class`. Do you get back "Class" or "Module"?

Comment: I renamed the class to Foursq and changed the controller accordingly, but now I get an SSL error saying my certificate is invalid. I had the same error when doing the auth process yesterday, but I had fixed it...until now.

Comment: No clue to the SSL error as I'm a novice in that area. Do you perhaps have a model named Foursquare or another foursquare gem in your gemfile that might be creating this Foursquare Module?

Comment: Yes, I do have a gem called "omniauth-foursquare" which I am using for authentication. This is probably causing the issue, but I need it for authentication.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12576/discussion-between-turd-ferguson-and-slicekick)

Comment: where i should put the foursquare class?

Comment: I would put it in the lib directory as it's a generic class that doesn't have logic specific to your application